# Make Hibernate reading optional for column

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

On Dev env, Database has column called CONF. 
on QA env, Same database, same table don't have that column.

now because of that On QA env. my code is failing, with exception     `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

I am searching some annotation from hibernate jargon which allows, 
if column is present it will map and read from DB
and if column is not present, it will skip and set default value without throwing exception. 
So that I can run my code on all environment. 
First place is it possible ?

Comment: @Transient wont help me.

Comment: i came to conclusion that  its not possible.